# Horizontally placed submit button and proper alignment of error messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to align the yes and no buttons horizontally and in the centre of the notification. Also, I want to align the title and description above the yes and no buttons in the centre of that notification.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fwsk1rq4/) of the below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form").validate({
    rules: {
      time: {
        required: true,
        number: true
      },
      title: "required"
    },
    messages: {
      time: "Please enter time(digit) in Seconds",
      title: "Please enter the title"
    }
  });

  $("#notify3").hide();

  $("#c").click(function(e) {
    if ($('#form').valid()) {

      $("#notify3").slideDown();

      var timeOut = parseInt($("#time").val()) * 1000;
      var str = $("#title").val();
      var str1 = $('#desc').val();
      $('.message').append(str, "</br>", str1);

      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#notify3").slideUp();
      }, timeOut);
    }

    return false;
  });

  $("#yes").click(function(e) {

    $("#notify3").slideUp();
    $(".cy").slideDown(500).delay(1000).slideUp(500);

  });

  $("#no").click(function(e) {

    $("#notify3").slideUp();
    $(".cn").slideDown(500).delay(1000).slideUp(500);
  });




});
```

```css
#notify3 {
  width: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30%;
  height: 85px;
  background: #CCCCCC;
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
}
#confirm {
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 40%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #FFFF00;
  opacity: 0.5;
  display: none;
}
.message {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
.message .y,
.n {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#form .formelement {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  width: 900px;
}
#form .formelement label {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  width: 110px;
}
#form .formelement label.error {
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px 0 10px 100px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  width: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div id="confirm" class="cy">
  <h3 style="text-align:center;">Approved</h2></div>
<div id="confirm" class="cn"><h3 style="text-align:center;">Reject</h2></div>
<div id="notify3">
    <div class="message">
        <div class="y"><input type="submit" class="submit" value="Yes" id="yes"/>
        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="No" id="no"/>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<fieldset>


<form action="" id="form" >

            <div class="formelement">
                <label for="time">Time(in Sec)* : </label>
                <input type="text" name="time" id="time"/>
            </div>

            <div class="formelement">
                <label for="title">Title* : </label>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title"/>
            </div>

            <div class="formelement">
                <label for="desc">Description : </label>
                <input type="text" name="desc" id="desc"/>
            </div>

            <div class="formelement">
                <input type="submit" value="Confirm" class="submit" id="c"/>
            </div>


</form> 
</fieldset>



<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="valid.js"></script>
```

Comment: just a side note, try pressing 'Confirm' multiple times ;)

Comment: [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/fwsk1rq4/2/) - i made your padding on your message class to top only, and then added 0 padding/margin in you y and n class

Comment: @MrCoder Haha...dat was m nxt query...bdw can u plzz suggest my some changes to remove multiple entries on re confirm...

Comment: i'm not great with jquery/javascript but have you tried disabling the button until the 'messagebox' disappears

Comment: Have a look at this, hope will help you, http://jsfiddle.net/fwsk1rq4/6/

Comment: @SrihariGoud that's just swapping the text to be above? (doesn't fix the issue here)

Comment: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fwsk1rq4/7/) almost does it @user1702, but it might just need to 'clear' the text after it has disappeared

Comment: @SrihariGoud   U r code is working undoubtedly..but the text still appears on re confirm...any solutn?? I have tried to reset the var values bt its still not solving that problem

Comment: @MrCoder still not working...the text still appears

Comment: @user1702, use functions `text` or `html` instead of append.

Comment: Append keeps previous text and appends the new text. so the word itself says.

Comment: @SrihariGoud can u plz make it work on jsfiiddle....m new to jquery

Comment: OK. sure. wait a minute.

Comment: Look at the answer below.

Comment: @user1702, Hi. can you look at the answer below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, look at the JS Fiddle here. I hope it will help you. 
Using some extra class for message.

```
<div class="cnfmsg"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fwsk1rq4/8/

New Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fwsk1rq4/10/

Comment: @user1702 Please look at new fiddle link.

Comment: @Srihari, still the div(.message) is not aligned center, this will get fixed only if you update the padding with 10px 0. Check out this http://jsfiddle.net/fwsk1rq4/11/

Answer (score 0):

try to remove `height:85px` from the `id "#notify3"` and update the class "`.message`" with `padding: 10px 0` will fix your issue!!

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fwsk1rq4/11/)